# R finding last instance of string in one column that is in a second column based on condition

Tags: r, if-statement, string-matching

I have a data frame in R with four columns.  What I want to do is if a condition is satisfied with a row in column A I want to match the value of that row in column C, and find the last instance that the value appeared in column B, and then add a number to that row for column D.  Here is an example of what I have, what I want.  If df$a==3 then match the value of that row in column C ("Jim") to the last time it appeared in column B, and then add 3 to that row in column D.

```
Have                                              Want
a    b    c    d                                  a    b    c    d
21   Jim  -    0                                  21   Jim   -   0
2    Jim  -    1                                  2    Jim   -   4
3    Stan Jim  2                                  3    Stan  Jim 2
2    Bill -    4                                  2    Bill  -   4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# a different sample with more variety was used
#> df
#    a    b    c d 
#1: 21 Joel    - 3
#2:  2  Jim    - 1
#3:  2  Jim    - 7
#4:  3 Stan  Jim 2
#5:  2 Bill    - 4
#6:  3  Jim Joel 3

# 1. determine the locations where a==3
x = which(df$a == 3)
# [1] 4 6

# 2. determine the corresponding names from c
y = df$c[which(df$a == 3)]
# [1] "Jim"  "Joel"

# 3. determine the locations where to add +3 to d
z = sapply(seq_along(y), function(i) max(grep(y[i], df$b[1:x[i]])))
# [1] 3 1

# 4. add +3 to those
df$d[z] = df$d[z] + 3

#    a    b    c  d
#1: 21 Joel    -  6
#2:  2  Jim    -  1
#3:  2  Jim    - 10
#4:  3 Stan  Jim  2
#5:  2 Bill    -  4
#6:  3  Jim Joel  3
```

Note : above case assumed that a value corresponding to `y` will always be found in `b`. But if an exception occurs : like assume first row of `b` had `jacky` then `max()` returns `Inf`. Therefore prefer

```
df$d[z[!is.infinite(z)]] = df$d[z[!is.infinite(z)]] + 3
```

Comment: Yes it does.  Sorry I just got around to testing on my problem, and it worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

its a little `grep` heavy but it works:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(21,2,3,2),
                 b = c("Jim", "Jim", "Stan", "Bill"),
                 c = c(NA, NA, "Jim", NA),
                 d = c(0,1,2,4))

target <- 3

df$d[max(grep(df$c[grep(target, df$a)], df$b))] <- df$d[max(grep(df$c[grep(target, df$a)], df$b))] + target
# or 
a_match_pos <- grep(target, df$a)
last_c_match_pos <- max(grep(df$c[a_match_pos], df$b))
df$d[last_c_match_pos] <- df$d[last_c_match_pos] + target

> df
a    b    c d
1 21  Jim <NA> 0
2  2  Jim <NA> 4
3  3 Stan  Jim 2
4  2 Bill <NA> 4
```